# How many power nodes are there in Dead Space?

Tags: dead-space

Power nodes seem to be rare to come by, with usually only one or less in a chapter.

Does anybody know many total power nodes there are in the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

36, <s>53</s> if I counted correctly. You also get 10 when you start a New Game+.

From http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/943338-dead-space/faqs/54711.

Comment: Thanks, but this is for Dead Space 2 - I'm looking for info on Dead Space 1

Comment: Oops. Fixed now.